# Manipulating named patterns inside replacement rules

Tags: pattern-matching, replacement

When I evaluate the following expression,

`{a -> "value1", b -> "value22"} /. {Rule[x_, y_] -> Rule[x, y]}`

I get `{a -> "value1", b -> "value2"}`, as expected.

But when I evaluate the same expression with a `ToString[]` wrapper around a named pattern, it is no longer recognized as a named pattern:

`{a -> "value1", b -> "value2"} /. {Rule[x_, y_] -> Rule[x, ToString[y]]}`

Result: `{a -> y, b -> y}`.

Why is `y` not replaced with the corresponding right-hand side values in replacement rules? How can I fix this?

Comment: `{a -> "value1", b -> 1} /. Rule[x_, y_] :> Rule[x, ToString[y]]` gives you `{a -> "value1", b -> "1"}`

Comment: @belisarius, got it. Using `:>` instead of `->` fixed the problem. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: To understand @belisarius comment read docs on `Rule` vs `RuleDelayed`